# How to get thread safe max value to find the next serial number using MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, stored-procedures, thread-safety

I need to generate the next certificate number using the last max number.

What I am doing now is as follows:

1. Get the MAX certificate number using MAX()
2. Add +1 to the MAX value.
3. Return the new certificate number.

   DECLARE lastNumber INT Default 0;

   SELECT max(certificate_type) INTO lastNumber from certificates WHERE certificate_type=1;

   SET newNumber = lastNumber + 1;

   INSERT INTO certificates (id, certificate_number, certificate_type) values (NULL, newNumber, 1);

Unfortunately this is NOT working and I am getting duplicate entry. The fact is when I am selecting the MAX() at that time other entry added during the current operation.

I also can not use the Auto-Increment id as there are different types of certificate number which has their own serial number.

```
id   |   certificate_number   |   certificateType
1    |   ABC-000001           |   1
2    |   XYZ-000001           |   2
3    |   ABC-000002           |   1
```

Is there any way to READ Lock the table until the current operation is being executed or any other solution to get a reliable next number?

Comment: Create unique constraint on `certificate_number` - Just a suggestion

Comment: Yes, I can unique constraint on `certificate_number` or I can  check duplicate entry before adding, but in that case I need to write statement for exception, so I am looking for some other isolated solution.

Comment: You don't need 3 queries. You only need an INSERT (just a slightly different INSERT from the one you're presently using)

Comment: Yes, I can use slightly different INSERT but what about the thread safe MAX number mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the table using `LOCK TABLES` as follows:

```
LOCK TABLES certificates WRITE;
-- your select and insert queries
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I thought that MySQL forbid LOCK TABLES in stored procedures from this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214678/why-does-mysql-forbid-lock-tables-in-stored-procedures